# How to get date and time from firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

When I console log my creation at the terminal it shows

"creation": Object {
"nanoseconds": 420000000,
"seconds": 1620290402,
},

how can i format it into date and time so i can use it on frontend

Comment: See the linked question and more from https://www.google.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bjavascript%5D+How+to+get+date+and+time+from+firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick format that I've used in the past for Firebase to JS strings:

```
    //Firebase Timestamp Fix

    creation = new Date(creation.seconds * 1000);
    const formattedDate = creation.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
    const formattedTime = creation.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true });
    const newDate = `${formattedDate} ${formattedTime}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript doesn't know anything regarding the firebase time stamp.It simply gives you the object

**So simply use toDate().** For further refernce check this source [toDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate) firestore